# What are the ways in which you can arrange 6 objects with 3 options each?

Tags: combinatorics

I have 6 objects:

- a, b, c, d, e, f
- each object can have an "option" of 1, 2, or 3.

As an example, we can have:

- a = 1
- b = 2
- c = 1
- d = 3
- e = 1
- f = 3

How many different combinations can we have like this? Order of the "letters" in this case does not matter. I was trying to figure out how to use combinations for this problem but I don't know since it's not the typical problem of how to uniquely "choose" 5 objects out of 10 objects total.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: You have to choose all of the 6 objects, but obviously their option does not have to be unique.

Comment: Are we choosing one option from each type of object?

Comment: This is not clear.  Say you only had $2$ objects.  Would there then be $3^2=9$ ways to do what you want or some other number?

Comment: @N. F. Taussig edited to reflect answer

Comment: @lulu yes, I think that makes sense once I do all the options on paper. Would that mean we have 3^6 = 729 in this case?

Comment: Yes, there are $3^6$ such choices.  Feel free to answer your own question.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Is there somewhere that explains why this is true? i would like the answer to include such an explanation ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the order of the letters does not matter, each selection can be expressed as an ordered sextuple: $(a, b, c, d, e, f)$.  Since there are three options for each of the six entries, there are $3^6$ ways to make a selection by the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).